# How do we find the number of bounded states in this potential?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

for the potential

$$V(x)=-\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{m^2}}$$

we can approximate the wave function and bounded state accurately for $x << m$ as simple harmonic oscillator, so what are we gonna do if $x$ is large compared to $m$? Is it the number of bounded state in this exact potential is no more than the bound state energy that is great than 0? How do we find the exact number?

Comment: Related exactly solvable problem: [Pöschl–Teller potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B6schl%E2%80%93Teller_potential).

Answer (score 4):

You can get an estimate that is correct (up to order one) from WKB. Given the Hamiltonian $$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} - \frac{1}{1+x^2/x_0^2}$$
the $n$-th level is characterized by
$$\frac{1}h \oint_{H= E_n} p\,dx = (n+\tfrac12). $$

The last bound state is at $E=0$, so the number of levels $N$ is given by
$$N = \frac{1}h \oint_{H= 0} p\,dx - \tfrac12.$$
For $H=0$, we have $$p = \frac{\sqrt{2 m}}{ \sqrt{x^2/x_0^2 +1}}$$ and the integral can be evaluated as
$$ \oint_{H=0} pdx = 4 \int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{2 m} dx}{ \sqrt{x^2/x_0^2 +1}}.$$

It diverges at the upper limit of integration (as the integrand behaves as $1/x$). Thus the number of bound states is infinite.

Comment: Note that in a potential $-1/(x^4+1)$ the number of states would be finite though...

Comment: Sorry I still have a little confusion since I don't know anything about WKB... I used numerical integration to find there are 4 eigenvalues that less 0, and the rest are greater than 0... I thought only energy greater than 0 are not bounded

Comment: @tjkt: call WKB in this context [Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_quantum_theory) and you might be familiar with that. If numerics only gives you 4 eigenvalues, then the numerics is wrong. You did not specify the Hamiltonian nor the Hilbert space though. I did assume you want to solve Schrödinger's equation on $x\in \mathbb{R}$...

Comment: so if it is true, does SHO have infinite bound states for potential <0 ?

Comment: @tjkt: the potential for the simple harmonic oscillator does not go to zero as $x \rightarrow \infty$. You cannot use the SHO as a model to understand the behaviour of your system as the energy of the bound states approaches zero.

Comment: In the limit $x_0 \rightarrow 0$, the potential looks like a delta function of weight $-\pi x_0$ and you only expect a single bound state close to zero energy. Does the WKB method fail here or am I wrong?

Comment: @Praan: I would argue that it is a bit simplified to think that for $x_0\to 0$ you get a delta function. It is the fact that the potential approaches 0 for $x\to \infty$ only like $1/x^2$ that allows for an infinity of bound states. A "true" delta function would approach 0 faster (already for $1/x^4$ you get a finite number of bound states).

Comment: Can you give me some hints on how to show this numerically? I have tried to non-dimensionlize this S.E.  to get the form of $1/2\frac{d^2}{ds^2} \psi - A/(1+s^2/A) \psi = B \psi$, where $A = V_{0}/\hbar \omega$ and $B = E/\hbar \omega$, and $\omega $ is the frequency of harmonic oscillator. By solving this, I got 4 negative values and the rest are positive.

Comment: @Fabian Ok, so you can think of this potential as a regularized $1/x^2$ potential and the spectrum has an accumulation point at zero energy. Thanks.

Comment: @tjkt I suspect the positive energies are spurious solutions. You probably need a very fine and large grid to find more negative values. This is to be expected since a state close to zero energy is only weakly bound. Maybe you can check the wave function of the ground state and first few excited states; they should resemble the wave functions of the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: @tjkt Upon closer investigation, I am positive that the positive energies are spurious and have not yet converged. In any case, you can never find the complete spectrum numerically for you would need infinite accuracy. Maybe a plot of the ground state energy as a function of the regulator $A$ (or $x_0$ or $m$) would be nice. In fact (for $V(x) = -1/(x^2+m^2)$) this is very interesting and related to singular potentials and anomalous symmetry breaking.