# Non-dimensionalize Schroedinger's equation for this potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, dimensional-analysis

I am having trouble non-dimensionalize this S.E. in order to solve numerically.. the potential is 
$$V(x)=-V_{0}/(1+x^2/L^2)$$

we know that $A = V_{0}/\hbar \omega$ is dimensionless, and  $B = E/\hbar \omega$ is also dimensionless, $\omega$ is the frequency. I used the $\omega$ to the one in the harmonic oscillator and got a dimensionless equation, but I only got 5 negative eigenvalues which show something is wrong, because there are infinite bound states.

Comment: What is A here? Is it an assumed value or something you need to evaluate? If you want to make an equation dimensionless, basically you want to replace all dimensionful quantities with a scale factor times a base value - for instance, $x=\eta L$. Now you replace that in the expression and integrate over the dimensionless $\eta$.

Comment: @tjkt -  *because there are infinite bound states.* Are you sure? That's not an infinite well...

Comment: The reason I think this is not right is because of this post I made yesterday...http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222125/

Comment: @tjkt: I missed that thread. Interesting.

Comment: @tjkt The reason that you only find five negative eigenvalues is your numerical accuracy. For more details, see my comments in the answer of your [previous question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222125).

Answer (score 3):

I assume we are considering

\begin{eqnarray*}
H &=&H_{0}+V(x)=\frac{p^{2}}{2m}+V(x)=-\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{2m}\partial
_{x}^{2}+V(x) \\
V(x) &=&-V_{0}\frac{1}{1+x^{2}/L^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Setting $x=Ly$ we have
\begin{equation*}
H=-\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{2m}\frac{1}{L^{2}}\partial _{y}^{2}-V_{0}\frac{1}{
1+y^{2}}=\frac{\hbar ^{2}}{2mL^{2}}\{-\partial _{y}^{2}-2mL^{2}V_{0}\frac{1}{
1+y^{2}}\}
\end{equation*}
so the important part is
\begin{equation*}
h=h_{0}+h_{1}=-\partial _{y}^{2}-V_{1}\frac{1}{1+y^{2}},\;V_{1}=2mL^{2}V_{0}
\end{equation*}

$V(x)$ is relatively compact wrt. to $p^{2}$ so the essential spectra of $H$
and $H_{0}$ coincide. This implies that their continuous spectra coincide
and equal $[0,\infty )$. In general $H$ can have continuum-embedded, i.e.
non-negative eigenvalues. In addition, if there are an infinite number of
eigenvalues they must accumulate in $0$ and there are no other accumulation
points. There exist advanced techniques to show that in this case there are
no non-negative eigenvalues. This is what in general can be said. 
But it suggests that you should look for eigenvalues close to $0$. This is to be expected since the potential is shallow.